# Carrierwave/Fog Ruby on Rails gem will not upload files to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have gone through the railscast and researched here on Stack Overflow. Although I have found others with the same issue, it doesn't appear that any of the other solutions I have researched seem to work. I have tried multiple variations of the code as suggested in other posts... No luck.

I am attempting to upload and store PDF files to [Amazon S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) via the *Carrierwave* and *Fog* gems to no avail. While I am using [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) in production, I have not attempted to deploy this to Heroku yet since I cannot even get this to work locally. The error returned is

> Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key

How can I fix this problem?

#### carrierwave.rb (initializer)

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider: 'AWS',
        aws_access_key_id: ENV['MY_KEY_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key: ENV['MY_KEY']
    }

    config.fog_directory  = ENV['MY_BUCKET']
    config.fog_public     = false
end
```

pdf_uploader.rb:

```
class PdfUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    storage :fog

    include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
    process :set_content_type

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue with setting the key_id, key AND bucket as environmental variables.  Once I changed ***all three*** to string constants, it seemed to work fine.  I also deployed to Heroku and verified functionality in production as well.

the final initializer file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider: 'AWS',
        aws_access_key_id: 'MY_KEY_ID_HERE',
        aws_secret_access_key: 'MY_KEY_HERE'
    }

    config.fog_directory  = 'MY_S3_BUCKET_HERE'
    config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and wrapping the variables on strings made the difference for me.

Instead of `Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id` I used `"#{Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id}"` to make sure the values get inserted as strings.

Here's my initializer:

```ruby
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: "#{Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id}",
    aws_secret_access_key: "#{Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key}"
  }
  config.fog_directory  = Rails.application.secrets.aws_s3_bucket
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000' }
end
```

And here's my secrets.yml:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  aws_access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  aws_secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  aws_s3_bucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  aws_s3_bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
```

Comment: Great answer @rebagiatte. I've had problems with this is in the past and didn't think to quote them. I'll add that non-secret config data can be kept in your config environment files (i.e. application.rb, development.rb, etc.) instead. They can be added like this: `config.aws_s3_bucket='xxxxx'`. You can access their values in your app like this: `Rails.application.config.aws_s3_bucket`.

Answer (score 0):

This error likely means that `ENV['MY_KEY_ID']` and `ENV['MY_KEY']` are `nil`.

Try replacing those values with strings that you get from the [Amazon AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) my account page.

So:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        provider: 'AWS',
        aws_access_key_id: "YOUR ACCESS KEY ID",
        aws_secret_access_key: "YOUR SECRET KEY"
    }

    config.fog_directory  = "YOUR BUCKET NAME"
    config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Comment: The `MY_KEY_ID` and `MY_KEY` placeholders have been replaced withe my actual id and secret key.  I simply didn't want to expose that info publicly

Comment: Understandable, but that is what the error indicates is that they are nil. Are they constant strings in your code or coming from somewhere else?

Comment: These are string constants... perhaps there is a way I can remove the form the initializer and bring it directly to the controller level??  I would guess that this is not recommended however..any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar issue with middle man setup.

In console I did `AWS_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxx'` and in my configuration file I have `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']`. It didn't work. However `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxx'` made the configuration file work. This is because "export mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment." while the first one didn't.

Hope you have the same issue and this helps.