# Trouble uploading files to Amazon s3 in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4

Able to upload files to Amazon s3 in my production environment with Heroku, but unable to do this in my development environment. Here is how the situation looks currently

Development.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

After following the advice of [this S.O. Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699300/rails-paperclip-s3-missing-required-bucket-option?rq=1#18705883), I created a file `application.yml` in my config directory with the following code:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "***"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "***"
AWS_BUCKET: "themoderntrunk"
```

I didn't change my design model though

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :thumbnail => "80x80#", 
                                       :small => "150x150>"
                                     }
```

When I'm uploading file's now, i get this error

```
missing required :bucket option
```

Many people I've seen had this same problem, but none of the answers have been able to solve my problem. Any guidance would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted your server to load `application.yml` into your environment?

Comment: Yea I have already restarted the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allegorically, this particular issue has commonly been resolved using  [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog), Ruby's canonical cloud services library.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'fog'
```

Run `bundle install`, then modify your configuration file as follows:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  },
  :fog_directory => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
  :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
)
```

Restart your server to reload the environment – uploads should work.

**UPDATE**:

Upon a rereading of your question, I noticed that you're to passing an environment global named `ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']`, but the variable you should *actually* pass is named `ENV['AWS_BUCKET']`. I suspect this is why the `missing required :bucket option` was being thrown. Renaming the variable *may* resolve your original issue:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'], # Matches global declaration in `application.yml`
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I be using a different bucket than the one I'm using in production??

Comment: It _shouldn't_ matter, IFAIK. I've updated my answer with a possible fix.

Comment: Alright I will do that now and see what happens. Should this gem change anything on my production environment?

Comment: It should not, though you can deploy using Fog in a production environment as well – it's what I use in my own deployments.

Comment: That solved the missing bucket error but now giving me the `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key` error. Gonna look into how to solve that one

Comment: Sorry, I had a minor typo in my previous code – you should be passing `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` and `ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']` to the hash. I've updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: Same error @zeantsoi... I'm sure your answer was correct, but something else must be going wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656145/1086529) should help resolve your issue. I've also updated my answer with additional insight on your original issue. If my answer helped address your question, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?